# SslStream and CRL/OCSP timeout

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, certificate

When using SslStream, both the 'AuthenticateAsServer' and 'AuthenticateAsClient' methods provide a parameter 'checkCertificateRevocation', which when true, seems to instruct SSPI to set the X509ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = Online.

In the case where the OSCP server is unavailable or not responding in a timely fashion, and CRL information is not cached locally, the underlying certificate validation may take a long time, as the default X509ChainPolicy.UrlRetreivalTimeout used by SslStream is set to {00:00:00} (infinite).

[image]

When validating certificates OUTSIDE the context of SslStream, the X509ChainPolicy can be configured to include a finite UrlRetreivalTimeout, and custom verification flags to ignore unknown revocation status:

```
X509ChainPolicy policy = new X509ChainPolicy()
{
    RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online,
    RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain,
    VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.IgnoreRootRevocationUnknown | X509VerificationFlags.IgnoreEndRevocationUnknown,
    UrlRetrievalTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5)
};

X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
chain.ChainPolicy = policy;
chain.Build(certificate);
```

I can't find any way to customize the chain policy used by SslStream. By the time a RemoteCertificateValidationCallback is invoked, the chain is already built with whatever chain policy SslStream decided to use. I can certainly configure a custom chain policy and build the chain inside the RemoteCertificateValidationCallback to get the behavior I want, but by the time that callback is invoked, the chain has already been built once, and the damage done.

How can I get more control over the SslStream internal certificate validation to avoid this long timeout issues when OSCP is unavailable?

Comment: Build with revocation off, and in the callback, if the chain was so far OK then turn revocation on, set a timeout, and call Build again?

Comment: Yes, this is the only workaround I've been thinking of doing. It's unfortunate that the chain needs to be built twice. I was hoping there was some other option I hadn't considered, but this is likely where I will end up. Thanks!